# What is more important, one semester less or a top final grade?

Tags: academic-life, germany, grades, time-management

So I (in Germany) have two options:

Option 1:

- finish my bachelor's in Maths at a renowned university now, with a very good grade (1.x), but not a top grade ("ausgezeichnet")
- finish my bachelor's within six semesters, which is the normal duration (*Regelstudienzeit*), but which is also lower than the officially extended *Regelstudienzeit* due to Corona

Option 2:

- finish my bachelor's in Maths at a renowned university a semester later, highly probably with a top grade ("ausgezeichnet")
- finish my bachelor's within seven semesters, which is longer than the usual *Regelstudienzeit* but is also still lower than the officially extended *Regelstudienzeit* due to Corona
- I'll probably also be able to do my master's in three semesters, so my whole studies will take five years (as usual)

Which option is worse?

Comment: Sorry but that question is far too much dependent on individual factors. And in the long run the answer is probably it won't matter at al

Comment: Which country is this? (Seems to be a German speaking one, but which of them?)

Comment: Country is Germany.

Comment: I'm not sure I find the close votes convincing. The dilemma in the question (should one study an additional semester in order to improve one's grade from (very) good to the best possible?) seems likes something that is common enough and which can be reasonably answered by pointing out relevant observations and (non-)consequences that many students might not be aware of.

Comment: @KGM: Thanks for the clarification. Does your university really use the term "summa cum laude" for Bachelor degree's with grade 1.0? I'm a bit surprised since it's a notion that is typically used for the best possible grade of  PhD degrees (although, semantically, it makes sense for other degrees, too, of course).

Comment: it uses the term "ausgezeichnet", which is a grade of its own, i assume it is equivalent to summa cum laude.

Comment: Have you encountered anyone or any institution that would care? I am from Czechia (so not Germany, but usually close enough) and I have yet to find anyone that would really care.

Comment: Its of course not that important, the question is, which is (slightly) worse... (I know neither option is really bad)

Comment: For what it's worth, I would definitely choose finishing asap.

Comment: What's your goal afterwards? For example, if you wish to do graduate studies abroad, some places only enroll new cohorts in Fall, but if you want to a short internship before graduate studies it might be perfect.

Comment: Afterward, I'll continue doing my masters, and I would probably be able to do my masters in 1 semester less so the overall time is normal.

Comment: (1) I took 8 years to do my bachelor's in engineering because I was doing it part time while working. When I graduated in 2021 and was looking for work the duration itself didn't come up even once with recruiters, we discussed the experience I gained in that time and it led to a positive outcome (multiple offers from various employers). My conclusion is that a resume with higher achievements, even if achieved over a longer period, is just as good if not better than one that showed lower achievements quicker.

Comment: (2) Then again, if your goal is to do a master's then that's the grade that will matter once you get it, nobody will look at your undergrad, so whatever gets you in the master's program quickest might be what's best for you right now.

Comment: Can you clarify why switching universities is an option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some employers or universities might be impressed by *summa cum laude*, so this could help you on the academic or job market in the future.  I'm not sure if *Ausgezeichnet* carries the same connotation.

I doubt either would even realise you spent a semester less on completing a degree.

So, if your goal is to have something to impress with on your CV, the chance of *summa cum laude* is more valuable.

Comment: Uh-oh… I've just edited the original question to remove the expression "summa cum laude." to reflect that, when questioned whether the BA grade was truly a "summa cum laude" (since the term is usually reserved for PhD grades in Germany), the OP conceded that this was their own translation of the German "ausgezeichnet". But now your answer doesn't fit the question anymore… How should we fix this?

Answer (score 16):

Here is a bit of general advice regarding the question "is it reasonable to spend additional time with my degree in order to obtain a better overall grade"?

**Disclaimers:** The following points are based on my experience with mathematics in Germany; things may vary considerably in other countries and, to a certain degree, maybe also in other fields. Not each of the following points might be relevant for the OP, but they might be relevant for other people who are facing a similar situation and read the question (and its answers).

**Things to keep in mind.**

- The OP mentions an improvement from the grade 1.X to 1.0. While this might be obvious, it is quite revelant what the value of X is. An improvement from 1.9 to 1.0 might be very significant, an improvement from 1.1 to 1.0 much less so.
- I would suggest not to look at the grade only, put also at the relative position of the grade within all students who complete their degree within one year. If there are, say, about 30 students per year who obtain a Bachelor's degree in maths at your university, then an improvement from position 2 to 1 might not be particularly significant, but an improvement from position 10 to 2 might be.
- The points made above might be particularly relevant if you are about to apply for somekind of scholarship during your Master's degree. For instance, for an application to the "Studienstiftung des deutschen Volkes" it is likely to make a significant difference if you are one of the very best students in the same year of your Bachelor's program or if you're only in the top 30% or so. (E.g., I think they somewhere have a rule that an applicant should typically be in the top 10% of their year. But I don't know how strict this rule is.)
- While the OP asks about a Bachelor's degree, I think it's worth mentioning that the points mentioned above might get more relevant for a Master's degrees, in particular if you want to do a PhD afterwards and are planning to apply for a PhD scholarship. Many such programs tend to be competitive, so depending on the program and funding institution, a somewhat better grade in your Master's degree can sometimes be relevant.

  (Please don't overinterpret this, though. It's probably not worth losing your sleep on a 0.1 difference in your grade. It's just one of several aspects that might sometimes be somewhat relevant.)
- Another point to consider is that it's not only the overall grade that might be relevant, but also the grade of individual subjects. If you want to specialize mainly in Analysis, taking an opportunity to significantly improve your grades in two analysis courses might be more worthwhile than improving your grades in a course in algebraic geometry (the same is, of course, also true vice versa). (But again, this reasoning is more likely to be relevant during a Master's degree and probably mainly if you intend to do a PhD afterwards. And even then, I again suggest not to overinterpret this.)
- On the other hand, some things to keep in mind when making decisions about the length of your study in Germany are: (i) Does this potentially affect your elligibility for "Bafög"? (ii) Will the additional time have consequences for the cost of your health insurance? (iii) In case that you are receiving somekind of scholarship, how will this affect the scholarship? (iv) And obviously: How does the additional time affect your overall finanical situation?
- As a general rule of thumb: Once you have a Master's degree, chances are that people will pay less attention to your Bachelor's degree (regarding the grades and regarding the time you took for the Bachelor's degree).
- Another general rule of thumb: Whenever your are facing a situation where somebody has to make a decision that somehow relies on your degrees, then the difference between one semester less and a slightly better grade is unlikely to carry much weight unless your applying for something very competitive (as, for instance, some scholarships that I mentioned above) or there is somekind of "pre-decision" made by a inflexible general rule or (worse) an automated system (but I'm not not sure how often this really happens). As soon as the decision is made by individuals who have personal interest in finding the most suitable candidate (say, a potential future boss, no matter whether in industry or in academia) chances are that these people will give much more weights to other factors, because they understand that such fuss as "did they take half a year more or less to study" or "was the overall grade 0.1 points better or worse" is a bad proxy for your performance.

**Story time:**

When I was applying for jobs in the industry after my PhD, I had two (very similar) Bachelor's degrees which both took me more than "Regelstudienzeit", a Master's degree which took me less than Regelstudienzeit, very good but none-top grades in each of them (1.3, 1.3, and 1.2) and a PhD. Nobody in any job interview that I had, gave a damn about half a year more or less or about why my grades actually weren't the best possible.

After I joint a company in automotive industry (not for long, though), I participated in a number of job interviews on the company's side, and again the same picture: nobody who was allowed to make hiring decision cared for such things. Everybody was much more interested on whether the applicants could actually explain, say, what they had been doing in their thesis, and why and how they decided for their major, and whether this person seemed liked someone you can easily work with. If there was a significant delay in one's CV, the question could occur what caused the delay - but this was mainly to see whether the applicant would give a reasonable answer at all.

I've been back to Academia (still in Germany) now for a quite while and the overall picture is the same. When professors hire people for PhD positions or as postdoc, they will of course have a look at the people's CV. If there's something really uncommon in the CV, this might give rise to a question or two during a potential interview (but again, many people will be completely satisfied if they get a reasonable answer). But it's very unlikely that an individual professor's hiring decision will depend mainly on such things as whether your Bachelor's grade is 1.2 rather than 1.0, or whether it took you half a year longer to complete your Bachelor's degree. People usually understand that human beings are not machines.

**What to do?**

Obviously, no one except for yourself can make this decision for you. I suggest to take the points mentioned above (as well as the points from other answers and comments) into account, check if some of them are particularly relevant to your situation, and then make the decision which fits your personal situation best.

My main advice regarding all of this: Relax. The matter is worth making a conscious and well-thought decision. It is not worth losing your sleep over it.